# Donation box management

Tags: web-apps, database, donation

Our organization has placed ~600 donation boxes across the country. 4 personnel are responsible for picking up changes and invoices from these boxes. This program has been running for ~4 years.

It becomes apparent that we need some sort of database to keep track of these activities. Specifically we need to know:

1. All the pick ups for the last 30 days to 6 months, sorted by date, or grouped by places.
2. The accumulated changes from each of the places for the last 60 days, to see if we should move the box to somewhere else or if we need a bigger box there.
3. The places that *haven't been* picked up for the last 60 days, to see if our staffs missed some of them.

We are looking for a simplistic setup, so ideally we want:

1. A software that runs on a Linux server, so that staffs won't need to install new software on their notebooks. We can self-host it but 3rd-party hosted solutions are great, too.
2. 2 staffs will be doing the key in job. No need for accounts and permission settings as the information is already public.

Is there any software recommended for managing this type of workflow?